# C assigning values greater than data type ranges

Tags: c, int, range

In **C int type** can having following **+ve range of values 2,147,483,647**

***source***:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

I would like to know what happens if I assign values greater than int can hold, how the values are truncated or what is exactly stored, if I do this

**int var=2147483648;**

Comment: For `signed` type it will result in integer overflow .

Comment: Knowing what happens when the rules are violated is typically of little use unless the specification calls out what happens. Most often though the only outcome is "undefined behavior" (abbreviated UB). What UB looks like on one system is not necessarily what it looks like on another, or even the same with certain changes in (often unpredictable) parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
int var = 2147483648;
```

The actual behavior for signed integers is *implementation-defined*. Most possibly the value will be narrowed (in other words "cut-of") to four least significant bytes (assuming that `sizeof(int) = 4`).

The constant `2147483648` is likely of type `long` (or `long long` if former is not enough to hold it), so what is actually happening here is like:

```
int var = (int) 2147483648LL;
```

The actual value after conversion is `-2147483648` as only sign bit is set (assuming two's complement representation).

Citing from `C11` (N1570) §6.3.1.3/p3 *Signed and unsigned integers* (emphasis mine):

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is **implementation-defined** or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

For instance, with [`GCC`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html), the result is to reduce result modulo `2^N`, which is effectively the same as bytes "cut off":

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N
>   to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Comment: yes i am using gcc and values are being mapped in some circular fashion..i wud check this on other machines as well.

Comment: @FalconZex: Just a very well meant recommendation: **do not rely ont this**. There is no knowledge gained investigating non-standard behaviour. Concentrate to write clean code, there is enough crap/broken code in the world.

Comment: @Olaf: Consider `short a = 0x40f2; a <<= 3; printf("%hd", a)`. Do you consider this code to be "crap/broken"? (i.e. integer promotion to `int` "behind the scene"). The underlying mechanism is actually the same as above. I am not implying that one should rely on this, but implementation-defined is not the same as UB, at least implemention _must_ document it.

Comment: Fair enough. Provided that it is well-documented and very carefully used in code to be ported (I should have differentiated more), but not for what OP seems to use it. In general, it is seldom a good idea to shift signed types if they do not have a value small enough to preserve sign. I do embedded programming mostly, and intentionally use mostly unsigned types.

Comment: @FalconZex: As I wrote in my answer, _unsigned_ integers have a well defined overflow behaviour (wrapping); you might think about using them instead of singed values.

Answer (score 1):

As you cited the linked statement, it is **wrong**. However, the linked page states **correctly** that it is valid for that specific implementation. Read the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) for *minimum ranges* of the standard types.

Actual sizes are in `limits.h`. You should not rely on anything else. If you need a specific size, use `stdint.h` types.

If you assign a signed value to an object which cannot hold that value, the result is [*implementation defined*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3).
A proper compilers allows to enable warnings for such issues - use them!

OTOH, for an unsigned value, it is very well defined (same section of the standard). Simply put, the upper bits are just ignored.

Comment: Technically the cited statement isn't wrong, it's just how one compiler implements the standard.

Comment: the size i have mentioned is similar to that mentioned in limits.h

Comment: @FalconZex: Problem is, you stated "**In C `int` type** ...", but that is true only for your (and possibly some other) implementations, not for C in general. Other implementations might have different limits (e.g. for an 8/16 bit CPU). Therefore my strong recommendation to use the libraries. Both have to be provided by any C compiler. It's all in the standard; it's really worth a peek (and not _that_ complicated to read imo).

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is no checking for overflow. The result is *implementation defined*.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if the type is initialised in the source code, as in your example, you could get a compiler warning or error. Compile with highest warning levels possible.

If the overflow is the result of a calculation, it would be undefined. In practice this results in a wrap around or truncation, possibly with an overflow error.